# InAppSettingsKit without saving to Settings app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, settings, nsuserdefaults

I've seen there is a library called InAppSettingsKit -  http://www.inappsettingskit.com/  - which lets your in-app settings mimic your settings within the Settings app.

But is there a way to get this to NOT use the Settings app as well? So it just allows you to change settings within the app. Or is there another library which does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InAppSettingKit lets you use a local bundle for the in-app part (see [documentation](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/)) Try only including this and not including the Settings.bundle

Comment: I can't find that in the documentation.

Comment: OK, thanks. Figured it out. I renamed the bundle to 'MySettings.bundle' and replaced a reference to 'Settings.bundle' to 'MySettings.bundle', reset the simulator and cleaned all targets,  and it works.